# Flag Inflection Points along Profile Line

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcpy

I have a 3D stream centerline shapefile that and I am trying to flag inflection points along the profile using ArcGIS Pro with Python 3, specifically where elevation changes by 0.5 feet or more. Here are some examples of the inflection points I am talking about:

[image]

I have a table with the vertices and elevation for each one. I added a field called 'Flag' to store which vertices are the inflection points.

[image]

How can I flag points where the elevation rises or drops by 0.5 feet?

Comment: Do you want a rise of 0.5 ft _in addition to_ [the usual meaning of inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition) (`f''(x) = 0`), or just the rise of 0.5?

Comment: Good point. I would like to include the usual meaning of inflection point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your data is currently represented in your program. If you can convert it to a numpy array, [`diff()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) calculates the discrete difference between elements

Converting to numpy arrays if you have the values in a list is as easy as

```
my_numpy_array = np.array(my_list)
```

Let's say you have the y-axis values in an array `y` and the x-axis values in an array `x`.

We can find `f'(x)` by

```
f1 = diff(y)/diff(x)
```

and `f''(x)` by

```
f2 = diff(f1) / diff(x)
```

[Pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) the length of these arrays with `nan` so that they're the same length as `x`.

```
f1_p = np.pad(f1, (0, x.shape[0]), mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan))
f2_p = np.pad(f2, (0, x.shape[0]), mode='constant', constant_values=(np.nan))
```

Then you can use numpy's [`logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to check for `f2_p == 0` and `f1_p > 0.5`

```
flag = np.logical_and(f2_p == 0, f1_p > 0.5)
```